# Find asio::yield_context from another function?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, coroutine

I have an asio coroutine that invokes a 3rd party library, which in turn invokes a registered callback function.  I need the yield_context of the coroutine within that callback, but am not able to pass it through the 3rd party library.

Is there anyway to determine the yield_context from the callback?  Some form of std::this_thread equivalent like asio::this_yield_context)?

If not, it seems I'll need to store a reference in a thread_local.

Comment: Thread local possibly won't work as you can have multiple coroutines executing on a single thread

Comment: What 3rd party library? What function interface? All well-designed libraries that allow user-callbacks have a "user-data" argument (like `void*`) that you can pass along. If your library has that, you can use it.

Comment: It's nghttp2.  The callback is registered before the coroutine comes into existence, and there is more than one associated with the object.I noticed that asio c++17 examples have calls like "auto token = co_await this_coro::token();" so it seems the mechanism exists, but I'm on GCC and it doesn't have Coroutine TS support yet.  For now, I'm copying the yield context address into a pointer member prior to invoking the library, and then accessing that from the callback.